# What does this error mean in TexMaker?

Tags: errors

I am new with Texmaker and earlier only typed with overleaf. In my project as I tried to quick build it ,  Tex maker shows this error-

```
{! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].\@fileswithoptions #1->\@ifnextchar [{\@fileswith@ptions #1}{\@fileswith@pti... \usepackage{}
```

While my body of document is like

```
\documentclass[article, 12 pt]
\usepackage{epsfig,epic,eepic,units}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}

\section{Prelimanries}
We define a Group ring, RG, where \(R\) be any ring and \(G\) be any group, to be the set of all formal linear combinations of the form
\[\alpha= \sum_{g\in G} a_gg\]
where \(a_g\in R\) and \(a_g=0\) almost everywhere.\\
\((RG,+,.) \) is a ring under + and . defined as follows-
\[\alpha+\beta = \sum_{g \in G} a_gg +\sum_{g\in G} b_gg = \sum_{g in G} (a_g + b_g)g\]



---- More text

\end{document}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Do you really have `\documentclass[article,12pt]`, and not `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`?

Comment: ohh thanks. It worked. `\documentclass[article,12pt]` works on overleaf  but not in texmaker. Thanks

Comment: It should make no difference if you compile that on Overleaf or on your computer, it's the same underlying system. The only difference is likely that Overleaf runs in `nonstopmode`, so when encountering errors LaTeX tries to do something reasonable, which in some cases can give you reasonable looking output. You should surely have gotten some error messages in Overleaf.

Comment: Hmm.Can you also tell me if I want to use `\chapter` control sequence and make chapters and ten sections, what should I do in above programme as it doesnot take in`\chapter`

Comment: See the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for specifying a documentclass is

```
\documentclass[<options>]{<name of class>}
```

so `\documentclass[article,12 pt]` is wrong. The correct syntax is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

If you try compiling a document like

```
\documentclass[article, 12 pt]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

on Overleaf you should see a message like this:

[image]

#### Using `\chapter`

As any basic LaTeX introduction will (or at least should) tell you, the `article` class does not define a `\chapter` sectioning level, as it is intended for shorter documents where having chapters is "too much". If you want to use `\chapter`, change to a `report` or `book`-like class. This includes for example the standard classes `report` and `book`, the KOMA-classes `scrreprt` and `scrbook`, and `memoir`. Hence, you want something like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
```